# What is the Brachistochrone curve with an initial velocity?

Tags: calculus, physics, calculus-of-variations

I'm basically trying to solve the opposite of the brachistochrone problem. You know how the  brachistochrone is the shortest path between two points A and B, falling under the influence of gravity? Well I'd essentially like to find the shortest path between two points A and B, however I'd like the object to be travelling upwards (like a projectile).

Essentially, I'm trying to find the curve that minimises the time that a penalty kick in soccer takes between two distinct points. Here is a picture:
[image: Diagram]

I know that the integrand of the T integral is $ds/v$. I'm just not sure how to pose this as a calculus of variations problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Another way to state this: What is the Brachistochrone curve with an initial velocity?

Comment: I think it is just a section of the vanilla Brachistochrone curve; I suggest you to post this on Physics SE also.

Comment: @Trebor ah thank you very much. That’s a much better way to say it.

Comment: No, because there is no physical “rail” or “pathway” like the original brachistochrone problem, instead a penalty kick always travel in the air with a parabola trajectory, there will be only two possible curves to consider.

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal how so? So there is no way to optimise the time of a penalty kick between two fixed points? Aren’t there an infinite number of curves between two fixed points? Wouldn’t one of them optimise the time?

Comment: But for a fixed g and given initial velocity, there will be always only two parabola that passes through the point. It may be easier to see this if the end point is at the same height at the starting point.

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal hmm. What if I don’t fix the initial velocity?

Comment: @ScratchCat as I said the ball must travel in a parabola in the air under gravity, so it is not arbitrary.

Comment: @ScratchCat then the problem becomes trivial, just shoot straight with a speed of light.

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal ah true. However, doesn’t it also depend on the angle

Comment: @ScratchCat yes, but per our discussion, there are only at most two possible angles (for each parabola) for any given initial speed.

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal Ah I’m in a bit of fix lol. This was supposed to be as part of a school paper on variational calculus. Is there no application of variational calculus in terms of this problem?

Comment: @ScratchCat maybe we can take away the part about penalty kick, and discuss in the more general problem as stated by Trebor

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal Yeah that sounds good. The problem, though, is that I need a specific application. Something like sport or something similar.

Comment: @ScratchCat a roller coaster comes into my mind...

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal that could be a good idea. Or maybe I could look at a section of slide in a park and compare it to the brachistochrone curve..?